# Does R have a string-like object that exposes a file API?

Tags: r, string, file

It's sometimes convenient to write a string to an in-memory object and then pass that object to functions in place of a file handle. In Python, there's [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO). Does R have something equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
con <- textConnection("the_thing_i_am_writing_to", "w")

cat("Some text without a newline", file = con, append = TRUE)
cat("more text with two newlines\n\n", file = con, append = TRUE)

writeLines(rownames(mtcars), con = con)

cat("this is after the car names", file = con, append = TRUE)

close(con)

str(the_thing_i_am_writing_to)
## chr [1:35] "Some text without a newlinemore text with two newlines" "" "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" ...
```

(`the_thing_i_am_writing_to` gets created in the environment for you)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `textConnection`!

Comment:  def view the help on it. it has an `encoding` parameter that may be needed if you're dealing with various locales or want to ensure UTF-8.